# How to create a list of lists in the config, while using ConfigObj in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, configobj

I am using ConfigObj in Python to read from my config file. I need to read a list of lists from the config file. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. sections and subsections - creates dictionaries, not lists
2. `list_of_lists = (1, 2, (3, 4))` - `ConfigObj` treats everything as strings, and produces the list `['(1', '2', '(3', '4))']`

What I would like to have (in Python context) is something like this:

`list_of_lists = [1, 2, [3, 4, ]]`

Can someone please suggest a way to do this? I'm open to alternatives as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the key you would like to use and the value would like for it to have?

Comment: @aquil.abdullah Sure. I've added that to the question

Comment: I've rescinded my answer as it doesn't seem to answer your question. What I did find was that __Values are always strings - if you want integers, or anything else, you can do the conversion yourself__. So it is up to you to deserialize any objects that aren't meant to be strings.

Comment: @aquil.abdullah there is int_list, float_list, etc. check https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validate.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach using configparaser

```
# Contents of configfile
[section1]
foo=bar
baz=oof
list=[1,2,[3,4,]]
```

Code to get list of lists:

```
import configparser
import ast
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read_file(open('configfile'))
s1 = cfg['section1']
list_of_lists = ast.literal_eval(s1.get('list')
print list_of_lists

# output
# [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by this way using `configobj`

ini:
`config/test.ini`

```
[List]
AA = aa,bb
BB = cc,dd
```

python:
`main.py`

```
# Read a config file
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj('.\config\test.ini')

print(config['List'])
print(config['List']['AA'])
print(config['List']['BB'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
# Read a config file
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj(filename)

# Access members of your config file as a dictionary. Subsections will also be dictionaries.

value1 = config['keyword1']
value2 = config['section1']['keyword3']
```

Refer to [ConfigObj Documentation](http://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html#getting-started).

Comment: Like I specified in the question, I need a list of lists, not a dictionary

Comment: @th3an0maly, convert a dict into a list of lists by `lists = [[v, k] for k, v in d.iteritems()]`. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because it can be used as a workaround along with some parsing. No because I was looking for a config reader that would provide this out of the box. Thank you.